# How to simulate cmd+v (paste) event in C/C++ on MacOS?

Tags: c++, c, macos, events, keystroke

Need to simulate pressing `cmd+v` in C++ code on MacOS to paste buffer in any active window.

Tried the following code, yet it only prints `v`:

```
  CGEventRef cmd_down = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kVK_Command, true);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, cmd_down);
  CGEventRef v_down = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kVK_ANSI_V, true);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, v_down);
  CGEventRef v_up = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kVK_ANSI_V, false);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, v_up);
  CGEventRef cmd_up = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kVK_Command, false);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, cmd_up);

  CFRelease(cmd_down);
  CFRelease(v_down);
  CFRelease(v_up);
  CFRelease(cmd_up);
```

P.S: If I change `cmd` to `shift`, my code still prints little `v` (not `V`）

Comment: Use CGEventSetFlags to set key modifier flags

Comment: Can't it be done this way? Even apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456564-cgeventcreatekeyboardevent?preferredLanguage=occ) send `shift` as an event.

Comment: You are right. Should work that way. Try usleep(50) between postings and try to create the events first and only then post it.